# Почему запрос mysql уходит в таймаут?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Салют. Не могу победить проблему в связке nodejs + mysql. Время от времени mysql запросы уходят в таймаут и как следствие не выполняются. Происходит это примерно раз в несколько минут.

Вот две наиболее частые ошибки:

```
(node:617890) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Handshake inactivity timeout

(node:618075) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: read ETIMEDOUT
```

Вот модуль:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const mysqlConfig = {
  host: 'externalHost',
  user: 'demo',
  password: 'demo',
  database: 'demo'
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig)

const db = {}

db.query = (sql, args = null) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error getConnection:')
        return reject(err)
      } else {
        connection.query(sql, args, (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error query:')
            return reject(err)
          } else {
            connection.release()
            return resolve(res)
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
}

module.exports = { db }
```

Использую:

```
const {db} = require('db.js')

const fn = async () => {
  const query = await db.query(
    'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?',
    [1]
  )

  console.log(query[0])
}
```

Пробовал ставить таймауты большие, но это лишь не много оттягивает проблему. В чем может быть дело?

Окружение:

- node v14.2.0
- npm v6.14.5
- mysql v2.18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, как избавиться от данной проблемы.

Начать нужно с того что вероятно проблема была не в ноде и не в пакетах мускла, а скорее всего в настройках самого мускла или в nginx который проксирует мускл сервер.

В моем конфиге был указан хост ( pma.host.com ) я его заменил на ип адрес своей локальной сети ( 192.168.1.5 ) и проблема перестала появляться (пока что)

Далее я не много изменил модуль взаимодействия с бд:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mariadb = require('mariadb/callback')

const mysqlConfig = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME
}

const driver = mariadb.createPool(mysqlConfig)

const db = {}

db.query = (sql, args = null) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    driver.getConnection((err, connect) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)

      connect.query(sql, args, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          connect.end()
          return reject(err)
        }

        connect.end()
        return resolve(rows)
      })
    })
  })
}

module.exports = { db, mysqlConfig }
```

Перешел на пакет mariadb. С пакетами mysql, mysql2 и тп не тестил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить mysql пакет на mysql2 который работает на Promise. Подключение и использование mysql практически не изменится:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2')
mysql.createConnection({
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_NAME,
            database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
        }).promise();

await mysql.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?;', [1])
            .then((data) => { 
                  console.log(data[0])
            }
```

Так же использование самых новых  версий node.js не лучший вариант, в связи с возможными ошибками, используйте лучше рекомендуемую версию ( 12.17.0 )

Comment: Попробовал все что вы предложили, но это не особо помогло.

У mysql2 та же ошибка с handshake, тестил еще пакеты (mysql-promise, knex) они либо не показывают ошибку в логах, но запрос все равно в пендинг уходит.

Нашел интересную зависимость: в данном примере у меня указан хост до бд pma.host.com, я его заменил на 192.168.1.5 (локальная сеть), поставил пакет mariadb и пока что не наблюдаю прежних проблем.